# Database connectivity through MySQL connector Python with CGI is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache

Actually I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and python3
so in that when I am importing MySQL.connector and CGI in a single file the file is not working showing the error

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi

import mysql.connector as msql
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped).

These both are not working simultaneously but working individually.

Answer (score 14):

I don´t know why but in my case changing the order on imports solved the problem

With this imports:

```
import sys, pdfplumber, json, io, re, getpass
import mysql.connector as mariadb
```

I get **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

I changed the imports order letting mysql.connector first

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import sys, pdfplumber, json, io, re, getpass
```

And my script ran flawlessly

It took me whole day to solve it.... hope it helps

Comment: python 3.6 ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Similarly I was using the schedule package https://pypi.org/project/schedule. Importing mysql.connector first and schedule later worked.

Comment: There is some possibly related information at this link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97220

Comment: Same issues I am facing. Thanks for solution. This also work for me :)